# Canvas width and height - webview

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, android-webview

I want to set height and width of the canvas to 100%. So my code is:

```
var bgSizeH = window.innerHeight;
    bgSizeW = window.innerWidth;
    gameCanvas = document.getElementById("game");
    gameCanvas.width = bgSizeW;
    gameCanvas.height = bgSizeH;
```

I'm using function below to restart game:

```
function stopGame() {
    location.reload();
}
```

Everything is ok in Chrome Inspect Tool. But if I'm putting this code to Android Studio my canvas looks like this:

[image]

After game restarting the canvas looks ok:

[image]

My WebView is set to 100% width and height. It looks like on the start of app the canvas is not set to 100%. I've tried to use `resize` function but it doesn't work.

**EDIT:**
console.log before reload:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "592", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (11)
[INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "288", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (12)
```

console.log after reload:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(11)] "640", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (11)
[INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "360", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the $(window).load() function rather than $(document).ready().

The $(document).ready() event executes when the HTML DOM is loaded and ready.
The $(window).load() event executes later when the complete page is fully loaded.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var b_height = $("body").height();
});
```